# How do I connect to my router through wifi?

Tags: wifi

I've bought a wifi adapter for raspberry pi, I don't have an OS, I'm running RetroPie so I need a console solution.

Someone suggested accessing:

`sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces`

and changing it to:

```
iface lo inet loopback
iface eth0 inet dhcp

allow-hotplug wlan0
auto wlan0

iface wlan0 inet dhcp
    wpa-ssid "ssid"
    wpa-psk "password"
```

I then reset my device like told and inserted the wifi adapter.

After booting up I don't know what else to do now to connect with wifi...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

> This applies to Raspbian Wheezy prior to 2015-05-05 for later (and Jessie) See [How do I set up networking/WiFi/Static IP](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/37921/8697)

You can do this but I would suggest `/etc/network/interfaces`

```
auto lo

iface lo inet loopback
iface eth0 inet dhcp

allow-hotplug wlan0
auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet manual
wpa-roam /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf

iface home inet dhcp
iface default inet dhcp
```

And put network in `/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf`
Mine is:-

```
ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1

network={
    scan_ssid=1
    ssid="*****"
    psk="*****"
    id_str="home"
    proto=RSN
    key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
    pairwise=CCMP
    auth_alg=OPEN
    eap=MD5
}
```

You may need to customise settings depending on your WiFi. Check out `man wpa_supplicant.conf`

Comment: I've tried something similar to this but my wifi dongle doesn't flash at all when it's in my Pi but it does in my PC. Do I need drivers sorted first? is that my problem?

Comment: Unless you have a B+ you probably don't have enough power. Use a powered hub.

Comment: I do have the B+