# Can't make two network interfaces at once work properly

Tags: raspbian, ssh, wifi, ethernet, connection

I'm having some trouble with my pi. I'm using ssh connection only - through cable but I bought WiFi USB adapter so I can also connect my pi from my tablet. Unfortunately when I reconfigured interfaces(in /etc/network/interfaces) and rebooted pi, I couldn't connect to it as usual - through cable but the led on my WiFi USB stick was blinking. Then I tried a lot of configurations but none of them worked properly :/

What I want to have:
-static eth0 address
-static wlan0 address
-possibility to connect with SSH through both eth0 and wlan0

Here's my /etc/network/interfaces at the moment:

> auto lo
>
> iface lo inet loopback
>
> iface eth0 inet static
>
> address 192.168.137.85
>
> netmask 255.255.255.0
>
> gateway 192.168.137.1
>
> allow-hotplug wlan0
>
> iface wlan0 inet dhcp
>
> wpa-ssid "MySSID"
>
> wpa-psk "SuperSecretPassword"
>
> wpa-roam /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
>
> iface default inet dhcp

And it's working for eth0 connection but not for wlan0. And led on my WiFi adapter isn't blinking even if I turn the GUI on, the program can't see this adapter - yes, drivers are installed, yes - when I check lsusb I can see it, yes - when I check lsmod I can see the module(used by 0)

Please help me, I'm a noob in RPi and don't know what to do :/

P.S. I'm running Raspbian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may eventually make your config work, but I suggest you start with the standard configuration. See https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/23373/8697 for an example.

You can if you REALLY need to set static IP addresses, but if you have a router use DHCP. If necessary reserve addresses in your router, but get wireless working with DHCP first.

Comment: Hm, I think that static IP for wlan0 is not necessary, But I need it for eth0 for sure. I'll try the idea from Your link
Thanks for reply :)

Comment: Wow, it seems to be working - I can connect with putty to eth0 SSH AND WiFi is working - thank You very much :D

Comment: But unfortunately I can't connect to it with SSH client on my android device through WiFi. What should I do to fix it? (It says: "No route to host" - rpi is connected to my home network)

Comment: Nevermind, after reconnecting everything is just fine. Thanks for help!