# How to configure my raspberry pi to connect to network?

Tags: networking, ssh, ethernet, windows, connection

I need my raspberry pi to connect to the network so I can be able to install certain packages into it. I went through this [tutorial](http://http:/https://learn.adafruit.com/downloads/pdf/adafruits-raspberry-pi-lesson-3-network-setup.pdf). I made the following changes to the network settings of the Pi.

[image]

But the problem is that the network I'm using is very secured in a way that for you to start browsing or use the internet you must firstly login as a user so I'm not familiar how I can add my credentials to the network settings.

Even if I try to use the ethernet cable I can't access the Pi doesn't connect to the internet. With the ethernet cable if I run the `ifconfig`  command I can see that it is connected to the LAN but the problem is that when I install packages it fail meaning it's not really connected.

`route` command
[image]

`ifconfig` command

[image]

`ping -c3 8.8.8.8` command

[image]

`hot google.com` command

[image]

`cat /etc/resolv.conf` command

[image]

I have run `nslookup google.com` , `wget --spider -v http://www.google.com/ncr` and `wget -v http://www.google.com/ncr` commands and this proved that my Pi is not connecting to the internet.

[image]

Comment: Please connect via Ethernet, then run the following commands: `route` and `ifconfig`, as well as `ping -c3 8.8.8.8`, then post the output.  This can help to solve the problem.

Comment: Please check http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/23369/how-do-i-connect-to-my-router-through-wifi/23373#23373 to see how you can set up WiFi on the Pi.

Comment: I have connected via Ethernet .

Comment: OK. Please post the output of `ifconfig`, `route` and `ping -c3 8.8.8.8` by editing your question.

Comment: Thanks for adding the information. Are you still having problems? It looks OK to me.  The only thing that we have not checked now is DNS, which you could do by posting the output of `host google.com` and `cat /etc/resolv.conf`.

Comment: Yes i'm still having the same problem , i will run `host google.com` and `cat /etc/resolv.conf` and post the output.

Comment: `/etc/resolv.conf` shows a T-mobile host as a nameserver, so that might work. I suggested a lookup of google.com to see whether there is a valid response.  If the `host` command is not installed try `nslookup google.com`.  Also, you could try `wget --spider -v http://www.google.com/ncr` to see if you get an HTTP connection, and whether it is re-directed to a Captive Portal.  To check further, remove the `--spider` and look at the file `ncr` (or the re-directed page with a possibly different name) to see whether it really is from google, or a redirected login page.

Comment: The wget command output shows that (a) DNS lookup is working and gives correct results, (b) you cannot connect to its port 80 and (c) you are not re-directed to a login screen (probably no Captive Portal). The connection problem is due to some IP filtering. Assuming this is not a firewall on your own computer (this is not impossible), it may be one by T-Mobile, your ISP. Please check with T-Mobile whether an **HTTP Proxy** needs to be used on this connection. If so, please try the wget command again after setting `export http_proxy=http://proxy_address:proxy_port` with the relevant entries.

Answer (score 4):

Usually these types of WAP's use something called Captive Portal, which intercepts http traffic on port 80, then redirects it to their login page until the user is logged in.

Try getting the terminal web browser package **links** and browsing to a website using a http (not https) and it should redirect you and allow you to log in.

Comment: The problem is that I can't download the terminal web browser package links. It is telling of the `connection refused` error message. Meaning it is not connecting to the website where it is supposed to be getting the package links.

Comment: That's not a problem since you do have `wget`.  This can write the HTML page in a file (unless it cannot connect, of course, which is the case here).  Then you could at least view the HTML file as plain text.